# Convert arrow2 chunks to Polars Series

Tags: rust-polars

I used arrow2 (specifically, io-odbc) to interact with a database. I saved the data as parquet with datatype `Vec<Result<Chunk<Box<dyn Array>>>>`. Example code below

```rust
pub fn write_batch(
    path: &str,
    schema: Schema,
    columns: Vec<Result<Chunk<Box<dyn Array>>>>,
) -> Result<()> {
    let options = WriteOptions {
        write_statistics: true,
        compression: CompressionOptions::Uncompressed,
        version: arrow2::io::parquet::write::Version::V2,
    };
    let encodings = schema
        .fields
        .iter()
        .map(|f| transverse(&f.data_type, |_| Encoding::Plain))
        .collect();
    let row_groups = RowGroupIterator::try_new(columns.into_iter(), &schema, options, encodings)?;
    let file = std::fs::File::create(path)?;
    let mut writer = FileWriter::try_new(file, schema, options)?;

    for group in row_groups {
        writer.write(group?)?;
    }
    let _size = writer.end(None)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

If I have `Vec<Result<Chunk<Box<dyn Array` how do I convert this type to Polars dataframe? Or more specifically `Result<Chunk<Box<dyn Array` to Polars `ChunkedArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Can't do that with `arrow2`, but as of `polars 0.35` it **does not** depend on `arrow2` anymore. Instead, it depends on `arrow-array >= 41`.

You can conver `arrow-array`'s `Arc<dyn Array>` into `polars`'s `Box<dyn Array>` and then to `Series`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677834/im-using-polars-with-connectorx-why-do-i-get-dataframe-type-error/77577085#77577085).