# I'm using Polars with ConnectorX: why do I get Dataframe type error

Tags: rust, rust-polars, rust-arrow2

I'm trying to get the table description from a Postgres database. I use ConnectorX with Arrow2 destination and I'm trying to store it in a Polars Dataframe.

Here's the connection definition:

```
use connectorx::prelude::*;
use polars_core;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

let source_conn = SourceConn::try_from(
    "postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/oceanics?cxprotocol=binary",
)
.expect("parse conn str failed");
let queries = &[CXQuery::from(
    "SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'spicyperfmanager'",
)];
let destination: Arrow2Destination =
    get_arrow2(&source_conn, None, queries).expect("run failed");
```

Then I try to extract the data from the query:

```
let df: polars_core::frame::DataFrame = destination.polars().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", df);
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/data.rs:16:45
    |
16  |     let df: polars_core::frame::DataFrame = destination.polars().unwrap();
    |             -----------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `DataFrame`, found `polars_core::frame::DataFrame`
    |             |
    |             expected due to this
    |
    = note: `polars_core::frame::DataFrame` and `DataFrame` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
```

Here's the cargo dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
connectorx = { version = "0.3.1", features = ["dst_arrow", "src_postgres", "dst_arrow2"] }
polars-core = "0.30.0"
```

I tried using the `polars::prelude` DataFrame, the `polars-core::frame` DataFrame, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong with the typing.

Answer (score 1):

`connectorx` uses `polars` v0.20.0, and it is incompatible with v0.30.0. So you actually have *two* versions of `polars`, and their types are incompatible.

Downgrade your `polars` to v0.20.0, and it should work.

Usually crates should expose the crates they import publicly to avoid situations like that, but it appears `connectorx` does not export its `polars` or `polars_core` (although it does expose `polars_io`, `polars_lazy` and `polars_time`).

Comment: is there a way to bypass this, perhpas with some unsafe raw pointers?

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov No there is not. The only way is to make the versions compatible, by downgrading your `polars` or updating `connectorx` to a version that has the newer `polars` if available.

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov Sometimes it is possible to convert the types by using some shared interface, for example going throughout `Vec`, but this is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As of now `polars 0.35` **does not** depend on `arrow2` but **does** depend on `arrow-array >=41`. So what I did was to leverage on `connectorx`'s `dst_arrow` feature.

First I convert `arrow-array`'s Field and Array to `polars-array` and then to `Series`, see `batch_to_df` in particular.

```rust
use connectorx::{source_router::SourceConn, sql::CXQuery, get_arrow};
use polars::{prelude::{DataFrame, Field}, series::Series, functions::concat_df_diagonal};
use polars_arrow::{array::Array, datatypes::{Field as PolarsArrowField}};
use arrow_array::RecordBatch;

pub fn conn() {

    let uri=format!("mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?cxprotocol=binary",
        "username" , "pwd", "localhost", 3306, "ultima");

    let mut source_conn = SourceConn::try_from(uri.as_str()).expect("parse conn str failed");

    let queries = &[CXQuery::from("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM xyz")];
    let destination = get_arrow::get_arrow(&source_conn, None, queries).expect("run failed");

    let mut data = destination.arrow().unwrap();

    let res = record_batches_to_df(data);

}
    
pub fn record_batches_to_df<I>(batches: I) -> DataFrame
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=RecordBatch>
{
    let mut batches_iter: <I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter = batches.into_iter();

    let mut dfs = vec![];

    for next_batch in batches_iter {
        dfs.push(batch_to_df(next_batch));
    }

    let res = concat_df_diagonal(&dfs).unwrap();

    res
}

pub fn batch_to_df(batch: RecordBatch) -> DataFrame {
    let mut columns = vec![];
    batch.schema().all_fields().into_iter()
            .zip(batch.columns())
            .for_each(|(f, c)|{
                let polars_field = Field::from(&PolarsArrowField::from(f));
                let chunk: Box<dyn Array> = From::from(c.as_ref());
                let s = unsafe {Series::from_chunks_and_dtype_unchecked(polars_field.name.as_str(), vec![chunk], &polars_field.data_type())};
                columns.push(s);
            });
    DataFrame::from_iter(columns)
}
```

P.S. I leave this step out, but the only little issue is that you need to know the `Schema` of you `DataFrame` upfront, since all `Array`'s come as `Binary` and *need to be casted*.See cast.

Also, if you get compilation issues due dependnecy resolution, see [my question](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574349/how-to-ensure-my-dependencys-dependency-version-where-they-use-xy?noredirect=1#comment136762636_77574349) on that.