# How to ensure my dependency's dependency version (where they use `>=XY`)?

Tags: rust, mysql-connector, rust-cargo, rust-polars

I have **two** crates (one for this example and second is the large prod version) with **identical** code, and identical following dependency's versions in **my** Cargo.toml *Example script compiles, and the other one doesn't.*

My crates have:

```ini
polars = {version="0.35.4", features=["lazy", "serde", "serde-lazy", "is_in", "diagonal_concat", "streaming", "object"]}
polars-arrow = {version = "0.35.4", features=["arrow_rs"]}
connectorx = {git="https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x", features=["dst_arrow", "src_mysql"]}
arrow-array = ">=46"
```

**Note** that **[polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/Cargo.toml)** uses

```ini
arrow-array = {version = ">=41"}
```

And **[connectorx](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/blob/main/Cargo.toml)**:

```ini
arrow = {version = "46", features = ["prettyprint", "ffi"]}
```

**PROBLEM**
See code snippet below (unfortunately, to reproduce you'd need a running MySQL server). My second crate does not compile with this error:
`the trait bound polars::prelude::ArrowField: std::convert::From<&arrow_schema::field::Field> is not satisfied`.

Whereas the my first crate compiles fine.

What seems to be happening is that **in my second crate, `ArrowField` [implements](https://docs.rs/polars-arrow/0.35.4/polars_arrow/datatypes/struct.Field.html#impl-From%3C%26Arc%3CField%3E%3E-for-Field) `From<Field>`, where `Field` comes from `arrow-array="49"`** and since connectorx returns `arrow-array="46" Field` - there is a conflict. However, my first crate is somehow able to resolve this issue. In my first crate, polars's `ArrowField` implements `From<Field>` for `arrrow-array="46"`, and code compiles.

**So the question ultimately is - how do I enforce `polars-arrow` to use arrow-array="46" , like it does in my first crate?**

FYI this is the code (which doesn't compile in my second crate)

```rust
use connectorx::{source_router::SourceConn, sql::CXQuery, get_arrow};
use polars::{prelude::{DataFrame, Field}, series::Series, functions::concat_df_diagonal};
use polars_arrow::{array::Array, datatypes::{Field as PolarsArrowField}};
use arrow_array::RecordBatch;

pub fn conn() {

    let uri=format!("mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?cxprotocol=binary",
        "username" , "password", "localhost", 3306, "dbname");

    let mut source_conn = SourceConn::try_from(uri.as_str()).expect("parse conn str failed");

    let queries = &[CXQuery::from("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM frtb")];
    let destination = get_arrow::get_arrow(&source_conn, None, queries).expect("run failed");

    let mut data = destination.arrow().unwrap();

    let dt_cl = data.clone();

    let res = record_batches_to_df(dt_cl);

}
    
pub fn record_batches_to_df<I>(batches: I) -> DataFrame
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=RecordBatch>
{
    let mut batches_iter: <I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter = batches.into_iter();

    let mut dfs = vec![];

    for next_batch in batches_iter {
        dfs.push(batch_to_df(next_batch));
    }

    let res = concat_df_diagonal(&dfs).unwrap();

    res
}

pub fn batch_to_df(batch: RecordBatch) -> DataFrame {
    let mut columns = vec![];
    batch.schema().all_fields().into_iter()
            .zip(batch.columns())
            .for_each(|(f, c)|{
                let polars_field = Field::from(&PolarsArrowField::from(f));
                let chunk: Box<dyn Array> = From::from(c.as_ref());
                let s = unsafe {Series::from_chunks_and_dtype_unchecked(polars_field.name.as_str(), vec![chunk], &polars_field.data_type())};
                columns.push(s);
            });
    DataFrame::from_iter(columns)
}
```

Comment: A hacky way would be to modify your `Cargo.lock` (not `Cargo.toml`) file so that the entry for `polars-arrow` uses `arrow-array=46`. As long as you don't `cargo update`, cargo shouldn't modify that dependency in the lock file, I believe.

Comment: would you recommend such approach to retrieve massive tables? I am trying to retrieve more than 70M records in a single query, any suggestions?